# Unable to use ec2 cloudwatch logs on windows 2016

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ecs

I added a \Program Files\Amazon\SSM\Plugins\awsCloudWatch\AWS.EC2.Windows.Cloudwatch.json file as explained to my user-data startup and restarted the ssm service as explained in the documentation for windows 2016. There are no errors in the ssm agent log. However, I do not see AWS.Cloudwatch.exe running, and no logs make it to cloudwatch.

I am really interested in just the application and system event logs and the \programdata\amazon\ecs\log directory. If I get that working, I will add the launch logs too.

Where can I look for clues? I did try starting the aws.cloudwatch.exe manually but don't know what the configuration argument is supposed to look like.

Here is my configuration

```
$ssmconfig = @"
{
    "IsEnabled": true,
    "EngineConfiguration": {
        "PollInterval": "00:00:05",
        "Components": [
            {
                "Id": "ApplicationEventLog",
                "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.EventLog.EventLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
                "Parameters": {
                    "LogName": "Application",
                    "Levels": "1"
                }
            },
            {
                "Id": "SystemEventLog",
                "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.EventLog.EventLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
                "Parameters": {
                    "LogName": "System",
                    "Levels": "7"
                }
            },
            {
                "Id": "SecurityEventLog",
                "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.EventLog.EventLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
                "Parameters": {
                    "LogName": "Security",
                    "Levels": "7"
                }
            },
            {
                "Id": "CustomLogs",
                "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CustomLog.CustomLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
                "Parameters": {
                    "LogDirectoryPath": "C:\\ProgramData\\Amazon\ECS\Log
    ",
    "TimestampFormat": "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                    "Encoding": "UTF-8",
                    "Filter": "",
                    "CultureName": "en-US",
                    "TimeZoneKind": "Local"
                }
            },
            {
                "Id": "CloudWatchLogs",
                "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CloudWatchLogsOutput,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
                "Parameters": {
                    "Region": "MYREGION}",
                    "LogGroup": "MYLOGGGROUP/win-host-eventlog",
                    "LogStream": "THISINSTANCEID"
                }
            },
            {
                "Id": "CloudWatchEcsLogs",
                "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CloudWatchLogsOutput,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
                "Parameters": {
                    "Region": "MYREGION",
                    "LogGroup": "MYLOGGROUP/win-host-ecs-logs",
                    "LogStream": "THISINSTANCEID"
                }
            }
        ],
        "Flows": {
            "Flows": [
                "(ApplicationEventLog,SystemEventLog),CloudWatchLogs"
"CustomLogs,CloudWatchEcsLogs"
            ]
        }
    }
}
"@

Add-Content "C:\Program Files\Amazon\SSM\Plugins\awsCloudWatch\AWS.ECS.Windows.CloudWatch.json"     $ssmconfig
Restart-Service AmazonSSMAgent
```

`

Comment: Have you assigned CloudWatch monitor IAM role to your instance?

Comment: Here are the permissions added, it sounds like you are referring to an existing policy?

       "ssm:UpdateInstanceInformation",
        "ssm:ListInstanceAssociations",
        "ssm:ListAssociations",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"

Comment: No, that seems correct. Did you restart the AmazonSSMAgent service after modifying the JSON file?

Comment: yeah it is the last line in the powershell script I posted here

Comment: For anybody finding this, one additional permission needed to be added to the policy: logs:CreateLogGroup in addition to logs:CreateLogStream. At least in our case, you may have preexisting log groups you are using

Comment: Hey Philip - were you able to get your script above to work, or did you have to install EC2Config on the Windows 2016 AMI as well? I have a script almost identical to yours but it's not working, so I started googling.

Comment: At the time I was never able to get this to work. I understand the ami's have all been updated now, so hard to say what current status is. I'm off on another project so won't be able to follow up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/UsingConfig_Install.html): 
The EC2Config service is not included in AWS Windows 2016 AMIs and you need to install it manually. Install it, run it, enable log integration, and update the JSON file (normally) located in the following path:

```
C:\Program Files\Amazon\SSM\Plugins\awsCloudWatch
```

Here is the configuration I have on my servers. It works fine and I get both logs and performance metrics.

```
{
    "IsEnabled": true,
    "EngineConfiguration": {
        "Components": [{
            "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.EventLog.EventLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
            "Id": "ApplicationEventLog",
            "Parameters": {
                "Levels": "1",
                "LogName": "Application" 
            }
        }, {
            "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.EventLog.EventLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
            "Id": "SystemEventLog",
            "Parameters": {
                "Levels": "7",
                "LogName": "System"
            }
        }, {
            "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.EventLog.EventLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
            "Id": "SecurityEventLog",
            "Parameters": {
                "Levels": "7",
                "LogName": "Security"
            }
        }, {
            "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.EventLog.EventLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
            "Id": "ETW",
            "Parameters": {
                "Levels": "7",
                "LogName": "Microsoft-Windows-WinINet/Analytic"
            }
        }, {
            "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.IisLog.IisLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
            "Id": "IISLog",
            "Parameters": {
                "LogDirectoryPath": "C:\\inetpub\\logs\\LogFiles\\W3SVC1"
            }
        }, {
            "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CustomLog.CustomLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
            "Id": "CustomLogs",
            "Parameters": {
                "CultureName": "en-US",
                "Encoding": "UTF-8",
                "Filter": "",
                "LogDirectoryPath": "C:\\Logs\\",
                "TimeZoneKind": "Local",
                "TimestampFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            }
        }, {
            "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.PerformanceCounterComponent.PerformanceCounterInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
            "Id": "PerformanceCounterMemory",
            "Parameters": {
                "CategoryName": "Memory",
                "CounterName": "Available MBytes",
                "DimensionName": "InstanceId",
                "DimensionValue": "{instance_id}",
                "InstanceName": "",
                "MetricName": "Memory",
                "Unit": "Megabytes"
            }
        }, {
            "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.PerformanceCounterComponent.PerformanceCounterInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
            "Id": "PerformanceCounterDisk",
            "Parameters": {
                "CategoryName": "LogicalDisk",
                "CounterName": "Free Megabytes",
                "DimensionName": "InstanceId",
                "DimensionValue": "{instance_id}",
                "InstanceName": "D:",
                "MetricName": "FreeDisk",
                "Unit": "Megabytes"
            }
        }, {
            "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CloudWatchLogsOutput,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
            "Id": "CloudWatchLogs",
            "Parameters": {
                "AccessKey": "",
                "LogGroup": "ASG",
                "LogStream": "{instance_id}",
                "Region": "eu-west-1",
                "SecretKey": ""
            }
        }, {
            "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CloudWatch.CloudWatchOutputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
            "Id": "CloudWatch",
            "Parameters": {
                "AccessKey": "",
                "NameSpace": "PerformanceMonitor",
                "Region": "eu-west-1",
                "SecretKey": ""
            }
        }],
        "Flows": {
            "Flows": [
                "(PerformanceCounterMemory,PerformanceCounterDisk),CloudWatch",
                "(ApplicationEventLog,SystemEventLog),CloudWatchLogs"
            ]
        },
        "PollInterval": "00:00:15"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I read that last section, flows as only sending the input, SystemEventLog to the output CloudWatchLogs, I must be misunderstanding something. How are the custom logs and other event sources getting added to your log stream?

Comment: You are correct, but this is an example. If you want to send CustomLogs, you should add it to the Flows section. I just wanted to make sure it sends logs to CloudWatch so I only added the SystemEventLogs.

Comment: Is the syntax used with the performance counters how you do that? a series of inputs inside of '(...)'?

Comment: Yes, it should be the same.

Comment: Hang on, have you enabled CloudWatch log integration on EC2ConfigService Settings?

Comment: In windows 2016 there is no EC2ConfigService from what I've been reading

Comment: For the record, the ec2ConfigService in not just not included, it is deprecated in windows 2016. This question is about the manual configuration via UserData script I showed in the original question. You only need to copy the a json file such as the one @mahdi shows here to ```C:\Program Files\Amazon\SSM\Plugins\awsCloudWatch``` and restart the ssm again, ```Restart-Service AmazonSSMAgent```