# Not getting CloudWatch logs option in EC2 Config Settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm not able to access Windows Server 2016 and also I'm not getting CloudWatch logs option in EC2 Service Properties in Windows 2012 Server. I followed each and every step in documentation.

Below is the EC2 Config Settings:

[image: EC2 Config Settings]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808967/unable-to-use-ec2-cloudwatch-logs-on-windows-2016/42812666#42812666

Comment: Thank you for your reply Mahdi, I followed your post and also followed http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/send_logs_to_cwl_instances.html#cwinteg-server2k16, still Iam not getting any logs

Comment: What is the IAM role associated with your instance?

Comment: {
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*",
                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: This is the Role Iam using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the IAM policy associated with the instance as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
    {
            "Sid": "AllowAccessToSSM",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:PutMetricData",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Also in the JSON file, the CustomeLogs section should look like this:

```
{
    "Id": "CustomLogs",
    "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CustomLog.CustomLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
    "Parameters": 
    {
        "LogDirectoryPath": "C:\\Logs\\YourLogFolder\\",
        "TimestampFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
        "Encoding": "UTF-8",
        "Filter": "",
        "CultureName": "en-US",
        "TimeZoneKind": "Local"
    }
}
```

Comment: After I entered this IAM rule, there are no errors in amazon-ssm-agent.log but still iam not able to get customlogs. @Mahdi

Comment: OK, you need to restart the agent service, did you?

Comment: This is my Custom Logs  "Filter": "test.log",
          "LogDirectoryPath": "C:\\servers\\log"  and Flow Section is like "CustomLogs,CloudWatchLogs" and restarted SSM Agent, But there is no result

Comment: Iam working on Windows Server 2012 R2, Iam restarting the SSM Agent after I did the changes in AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.json file.

Comment: Restart EC2Config service as well.

Comment: I enabled cloudwatch plugin in ec2config and restarted ec2config service. In console Iam getting only LogGroup name and LogStream name, LogStream is empty.